# How to get orientation of device in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, imageview

I showing image in imageview which is captured by Intent method of android camera. I have been tested this code over Samsung Nexus but when i tested over Nexus S, image is shwoing rotated by itself on 270 degree. I have been go through these links

[ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE orientation problem on Nexus S and Samsung Galaxy S I9000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143622/action-image-capture-orientation-problem-on-nexus-s-and-samsung-galaxy-s-i9000)

[Camera/picture orientation in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465835/camera-picture-orientation-in-android)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setRotation%28int%29

[Picture orientation from gallery/camera intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517634/picture-orientation-from-gallery-camera-intent)

But this code

```
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface("filepath");
exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
```

always giving 0 in both devices. Please tell i would i know that image is showing in which angle in particular device while showing so that it will be applied for all devices, once i will get its angle i will rotate by myself. Thanks in advance.

Comment: or this [http://mobisocial.stanford.edu/news/2011/08/rotating-images-in-android/](http://mobisocial.stanford.edu/news/2011/08/rotating-images-in-android/)

Comment: Here's my solution to this issue; http://stackoverflow.com/a/8864367/137404

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand what you're looking for, but if you want the orientation of the device, check out this question:

[Check orientation on Android phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795833/check-orientation-on-android-phone)

Comment: i tried getResources().getConfiguration().orientation. But still same result 1 on both devices.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Because if you just want to set the orientation, instead of checking what the orientation currently is, that should be a little easier.

Answer (score 0):

what happens if you:

```
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface("filepath");
exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION);
```

?

Comment: It always give 0 in both devices. Nexus which shows fine and Nexus S which shows image in landscape or rotates image.

Comment: have you read over this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450539/images-taken-with-action-image-capture-always-returns-1-for-exifinterface-tag-or/8864367#8864367 ?

Comment: It seems that there is a bug explaining your mentioned behaviour of the exif tag.

Comment: Yeah! i read that. But it is giving runtime error on this line


Cursor mediaCursor = content.query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new String[] {MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION, MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE }, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED + ">=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(captureTime/1000 - 1)}, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED + " desc");

Comment: have you mor information about this? a Stacktrace? Maybe you are just missing a permission.